# HTML text field to behave like a password field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a registration form, and i want to use a password field. The problem is, i want it to have a placeholder saying "Password" at the begining so i'm using a text field instead. I need to turn the characters into asterisks or black circles like a password field when the user starts typing.
I've tried changing the "type" attribute to "password" through javascript, so i'm stuck.
Is there a simple way to resolve this with css? or does anyone know of a good javascript(preferably jquery) to hack this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hover a `div` or a `span` tag over your text (password) field, then hide it when the password field takes focus or the div/span is clicked.

Answer (score 12):

1. Use a regular password field
2. Don't abuse the `value` as a placeholder — it becomes invisible to, among others, screen reader users.
3. Put the label in a `<label>`
4. Position the label behind the input
5. Restyle the input with JS to change the background

Demo at http://dorward.me.uk/tmp/label-work/example.html

Comment: @Anonymous, blind people do, on occasion, spend money. So it seems reasonable to cater to their limitations.

Comment: @Anonymous: Given that it may be illegal to block access to them in this way (depending on the jurisdictions you operate in and the type of project you are working on) — **yes**. Given that they may contribute to whatever revenue stream the site is operating — **yes**. And if practical reasons aren't enough then they are people and deserve better then to have additional barriers placed in front of them by lazy or ignorant developers!

Comment: David, i totally agree with you, i always put an invisible label pointing to the field

Comment: @David Dorward +1 to your comments and answer because catering for vision impaired *is* important, and there are people out there thanking you for doing your bit.

Comment: I agree with the financial and moral standpoints, but discrimination against the blind should always be perfectly legal on your own site, especially in non-commercial venues. EDIT: Sorry, I didn't want this to grow into a debate.

Comment: @Anonymous, while I agree with the general principle that 'the management reserves the right to refuse service,' I *cannot* support the right to discriminate against a group of people due to a disability. Though I may be biased, due to my own diabetes (which attracts a level of discrimination when it comes to employment opportunities and the right to drive certain classes of vehicle). I don't think blind people require any more disincentive to use the internet (a primarily visual medium) than they already experience.

Comment: So you think that it should be illegal for me to make a site that is composed solely of img tags without alt text? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @Anonymous — you said "Sorry, I didn't want this to grow into a debate" — please stop fuelling it. The relative merits legal backing of the two sides of this discussion aren't a programming issue.

Comment: @Anonymous: I wish I was that idiot. I'd have made tons of money. You should wish that as well, given you can get past your prejudices.

Comment: I have nothing against the blind, I just can't be bothered to design my site around them.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the HTML5 [`placeholder` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp) However, that will not work in all browsers (especially older ones).

```
<input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Enter Password" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, browsers frown at changing the `type` attribute of `input` elements via JavaScript. Most workarounds involve cloning the `input` with the new `type`, and removing the original.

You could absolutely position the label over the input form, and remove it on focus.

You should consider the implications of not using `type="password"` - it is the semantically correct option.

#### Update

Upon reading [David Dorward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777230/html-text-field-to-behave-like-a-password-field/4777247#4777247), you should strongly consider his very valid points.

Comment: Your javascript solution seems to be incorrect. The field becomes unusable. The best solution is the label's one, I think.

Comment: @CronosS Oh yes, of course, you will lose the value :P. I have just came back from holiday... I removed the example :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, where I had the Value of the inputs as my labels, and when you clicked inside one, some Javascript would run, clearing the input. But on the password field, you needed to change the input type from "text" to "password", which works in browsers like Safari or Firefox, but not IE (IE doesn't support the setAttribute function very well). So I was killing myself trying to figure out how best to do this (IE conditionals, etc.)

I found this thread, and I think Quentin had the best idea. Not only because it works and should work in all browsers, but it also provides an actual Label in the code, which, Screenreaders aside, is good practice. Plus, you should always consider those who use screenreaders to some extent.

Here is the basics of the solution:
The HTML:

```
<label>Enter Password
<input type="password" name="password" class="input" /></label>
```

The jQuery (note: I am not a jQuery expert. This could probably be written better or more efficient, but for two fields, it works):

```
$("input[name=password]").focus(function() {
    var value = $("input[name=password]").val();
    if(value == "") {
        $(this).toggleClass("inputBg");
    }
});

$("input[name=password]").blur(function() {
    var value = $("input[name=password]").val();
    if(value == "") {
        $(this).toggleClass("inputBg");
    }
});
```

The CSS starts with the Label tag, styled the same as your input class, with a position relative and display block added. Then there are two classes for the input. One that is the correct width, height, etc. positioned absolute, with a higher z-index than the label, BUT WITH NO BACKGROUND. The second class is exactly the same, but WITH THE BACKGROUND.

The jQuery just toggles between the two classes, so you'll see the label under the input, but when you click on the input, the background appears and you can type in text on top of it. Works great, should work in all browsers (although only tested in Safari on Mac and IE/Firefox on Windows). Nice idea Quentin!