# Django auth-app password masking - any way to turn off?

Tags: django, security

I keep seeing articles suggesting that [Password masking be disabled](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/passwords.html), so users can see what they're typing. When using the Django (V1.2) auth application, it automatically masks the password-input field. Is there any *simple*, possibly built-in, way to change that behavior, to make passwords visible?

I suspect there's nothing simple :) And it will require coding - designing my own forms, or subclassing existing ones or something. If so, what's the best way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could **not** use the widget to render the input for the password field.  That is replace:

```
<td>{{ form.password }}</td>
```

with

```
<td><input type="text" name="password" id="id_password" /></td>
```

in the template you use for the login page.

Comment: Very simple, thanks. Originally I was using {{ form.as_p }}, but explicitly creating the HTML input fields is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

In django/contrib/auth/formspy

Find the lines

```
password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput
```

Having this as PasswordInput is whats causing the masking. You can change it to text input if you want.

I would do it cleaner though and either do my own form or at least inherit from the form and write my own ExtendedUserCreationForm overriding the default field definition.

Comment: Agreed. Much better to alter the widget with a custom form than hard-code the input as the other answer suggests.

Comment: @chrisdpratt, ah, which answer are you agreeing with? :)

Answer (score 0):

The other posts addressed how to change the default widgets. I'll answer the post a bit differently.

First of all, it is not django that is masking the password, it is the default behaviour of browsers when you are using a [input of type password](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

Afaik, there is no way around it. I've tried to research a bit if browsers have any additional security provisions that would advise NOT to change the type, but haven't found any yet.

But from what I have read, it seems that it is advised to use a password field - still have to look on this.

There are though, some techniques that work around this neatly. most are js dependent though.

like:
[HTML text field to behave like a password field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777230/html-text-field-to-behave-like-a-password-field)

http://blog.decaf.de/2009/07/iphone-like-password-fields-using-jquery/

the "how" to implement this with django is more or less answered already ;)

edit1: found several references recommending the use of the password type (and therefore go through the pains of using tricks with two fields as in the links I posted).

There are some extra checks on password fields that do not apply to regular text inputs, in order to prevent XSS vulnerabilites: it seems that password fields are on some browsers adhere to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). But there are several other problems, like password managers (anybody using the browser could find out the password as the text type password field would be visible), etc.. etc...

Btw, a quick [google search with stop masking passwords](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=stop%20masking%20passwords#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=stop%20masking%20passwords&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=e7386a9c3eba4fdd) shows up with quite a lot of people saying not agreeing with unmasking.

The iphone like password field is a nice middle ground, but I guess it all depends on the balance between security & usability. How often do you login into a site with a friend/colleague sitting beside you?

Comment: Why are password fields advised? The only thing I see them do is mask the field, which I don't want. Unless you're using HTTPS, passwords are *sent* in the clear, so there's no additional security over a text field.

Comment: sorry, for the many edits, but i couldnt understand my own answer after i read it ;)

Comment: However, one of those *in favor of* stopping masking, is [Bruce Schneier](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/06/the_problem_wit_2.html), who certainly knows more about security than I do. :)

Comment: Sigh... well, until he [retracted his original statement](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/the_pros_and_co.html), anyway... I'm considering a toggle switch...

Comment: Password masking is like most things in security. Take many enterprises blocking downloads of zip files for example. Is every zip file a virus? Of course not, but it *could* contain one, so it gets blocked by corporate content filters. 99 times out of 100, nothing will probably happen negatively whether the password field is masked or not, but in that one case, you'll wish it had been masked.